# How can I type two If Condition?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, if

I have two promocodes, one is for X Bank and the another one Y Bank, I have just one DE with X Bank Subscribers and Y Bank Subscribers.
I want to create one function that shows Promocode X Bank to the X Bank Subscribers and Promocode Y to the Y Bank Subscribers and to the others Subscribers a general copy. Can you help me please!

Comment: Please read How to Ask. Right now, your question is incomplete. You've told us what you want to do, but what have you tried so far? You should edit your question to include additional details

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sparse details you provided, likely a simple IF/ELSEIF conditional should meet your needs:

```
%%[

   SET @Bank = AttributeValue("Bank")

  IF @Bank == "X" THEN

    SET @promoCode = "BankXPromoCode"

  ELSEIF @Bank == "Y" THEN

    SET @promoCode = "BankYPromoCode"

  ELSE

    /* Exception action - e.g. default code */

  ENDIF

]%%
```

you then just output the promoCode variable in your html:

`Your promo code is %%=v(@promoCode)=%%!`